# Remove element from an array of objects while iterating

Tags: c#, arrays

I have a list of id/parents that i'm iterating through an external extension.
This list can have around 11 000 lines and that's why i need to remove some elements so i will just display the ones i need.

**List of elements:**

```
FlatData[] elements = new FlatData[]
{
   new FlatData {Id = 3, ParentId = 1, Text = "A"}, 
   new FlatData {Id = 4, ParentId = 1, Text = "D"},
   new FlatData {Id = 5, ParentId = 2, Text = "E"},
   new FlatData {Id = 7, ParentId = 2, Text = "G"},
   new FlatData {Id = 8, ParentId = 4, Text = "H"},
   new FlatData {Id = 9, ParentId = 8, Text = "H"},
   new FlatData {Id = 10, ParentId = 3, Text = "I"},
   new FlatData {Id = 11, Text = "I"},
};
```

While i'm iterating, i want to remove some elements so they will not be processed or displayed, but the element i want to remove still present in the output !

Here's the code iterating trough the elements:

```
int firstDepth = 0;

IEnumerable <DeepNodeData> nodes = elements.Where(x => x.Id >= 5).RecursiveJoin(element => element.Id,
     element => element.ParentId,
    (FlatData element, int index, int depth, IEnumerable<DeepNodeData> children) =>
     {
          int  position;

          if(depth == 0){
            firstDepth++;
          }

          if(firstDepth > 0){
              position= Array.FindIndex(elements, row => row.Id == index);
              elements.Skip(position);

             // or much better, exit the program with something like break ?;
          }

          return new DeepNodeData()
          {
              Id = element.Id,
              Index = index,
              Text = element.Text,
              Children = children
          };
    });
```

I only know the starting position (the id = 4) which is the root parent. I will only know the positions of the elements i want to remove once i have the depth value. The idea is to display only the childrens attached to the id = 4.
Here's the elements i should have at the end and that should be processed to built my treeview:

```
FlatData[] elements = new FlatData[]
 {
     new FlatData {Id = 4, ParentId = 1, Text = "D" },
     new FlatData {Id = 8, ParentId = 4, Text = "H" },
     new FlatData {Id = 9, ParentId = 8, Text = "H" },
 };
```

The final output should be this :

```
    [
    {
    "id": 4,
    "index": 1,
    "depth": 0,
    "parentId": 0,
    "text": "D",
    "children": [
       {
       "id": 8,
       "index": 1,
       "depth": 1,
       "parentId": 0,
       "text": "H",
       "children": [
          {
           "id": 9,
           "index": 1,
           "depth": 2,
           "parentId": 0,
            "text": "H",
            "children": []
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
   }
  ]
```

**The recursive extension :**

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> RecursiveJoin<TSource, TKey, TResult>(this 

    IEnumerable<TSource> source,
         Func<TSource, TKey> parentKeySelector,
         Func<TSource, TKey> childKeySelector,
         Func<TSource, int, int, IEnumerable<TResult>, TResult> resultSelector,
         IComparer<TKey> comparer)
      {
        // prevent source being enumerated more than once per RecursiveJoin call
        source = new LinkedList<TSource>(source);

        // fast binary search lookup
        SortedDictionary<TKey, TSource> parents = new SortedDictionary<TKey, TSource>(comparer);
        SortedDictionary<TKey, LinkedList<TSource>> children
           = new SortedDictionary<TKey, LinkedList<TSource>>(comparer);

        foreach (TSource element in source)
        {
          parents[parentKeySelector(element)] = element;

          LinkedList<TSource> list;

          TKey childKey = childKeySelector(element);

          if (!children.TryGetValue(childKey, out list))
          {
            children[childKey] = list = new LinkedList<TSource>();
          }

          list.AddLast(element);
        }

        // initialize to null otherwise compiler complains at single line assignment
        Func<TSource, int, IEnumerable<TResult>> childSelector = null;

        childSelector = (TSource parent, int depth) =>
        {
          LinkedList<TSource> innerChildren = null;

          if (children.TryGetValue(parentKeySelector(parent), out innerChildren))
          {
            return innerChildren.Select((child, index)
               => resultSelector(child, index, depth , childSelector(child, depth + 1)));
          }
          return Enumerable.Empty<TResult>();
        };

        return source.Where(element => !parents.ContainsKey(childKeySelector(element)))
           .Select((element, index) => resultSelector(element, index, 0 ,childSelector(element, 1)));
      }
```

Comment: LINQ's Skip method returns a new enumerable, it doesn't change the state of the enumerable it was called on.

Comment: how to change the state of the enumerable ? do you have an example ?

Comment: Just assign back onto itself. `elements = elements.Skip(position);`

Comment: Why can't you ```Where(x => x.Id != 7 && x.Id != 11)```?

Comment: `Skip` does not skip a specific element index, it skips the specified number of elements from the current location (and returns the remaining elements).

Comment: @JonathonChase it says that i cannot implicitly convert  System.Collection.Generic.IEnumerable<FlatData > in FlatData[]

Comment: Shouldn't the results also include an element with an ID of 10? It too has a parent of 8.

Comment: @JohnWu, you are right. I updated my post

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
.Where(x => x.Id >= 5)
```

try

```
.Where(x => x.Id >= 5 && x.Id != 11)
```

If you don't know the ID but know the index (offset into the list), you can get the index using an [alternative overload of `Where`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549418(v=vs.110).aspx), which supplies the index to the where delegate as a second argument.

```
    .Where
    (
        (row, index) => row.Id >  5  //Filter on data
                     && index  != 11 //Filter on row index
    )
```

or you could simply do this (which is slightly less efficient):

```
.Where(x => x.Id >= 5 && x.Id != elements[11].Id)
```

If (based on your edits) you are looking for a list of children and grandchildren, given a parent ID, you can use a method like this one to search the tree:

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static IEnumerable<FlatData> GetDescendents(this IEnumerable<FlatData> This, int rootId)
    {
        var rootItem = This.Single( x => x.Id == rootId );
        var queue = new Queue<FlatData>( new [] { rootItem } );
        while (queue.Count > 0)
        {
            var item = queue.Dequeue();
            yield return item;
            foreach (var child in This.Where( x => x.ParentId == item.Id )) 
            {
                queue.Enqueue(child);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then use

```
var filtered = elements.GetDescendents(4);
```

[Example on DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/d9B8TR)

If you need to limit the levels, you can try this approach, which is less efficient but makes it clear which level each child is at and when to stop the search:

```
public static IEnumerable<FlatData> GetDescendents(this IEnumerable<FlatData> This, int rootId, int maxDepth)
{
    var results = Enumerable.Range(0, maxDepth+1 ).Select( i => new List<FlatData>() ).ToList();
    results[0].Add
    (
        This.Single( x => x.Id == rootId ) 
    );
    for (int level = 1; level <= maxDepth; level++)
    {
        results[level].AddRange
        (
            results[level-1].SelectMany
            ( 
                x => This.Where( y => y.ParentId == x.Id )
            )
        );
    }
    return results.SelectMany( x => x );
}
```

[Example on DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/YaN0Kc)

Comment: I only know the starting position (the root) and not the id 11. The id 11 i have to find it after some logic inside the Recursive function.  i didnt post all the code to keep my post simple

Comment: I added a second example to demonstrate how to filter on rowset index.

Comment: John Wu, i updated my post. Now you will understand my need better

Comment: I create a new post with more details. I dont want to delete that one cause SOF doesn't suggest it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50865869/remove-elements-from-a-list-of-objects-while-iterating

Comment: Yet another example for the recursive search.

Comment: Thanks for your exemple, i will try it out. But i cannot just keep my Recursive function and exit the program or the iteration once i hit the second depth == 0 ? Cause this will solve my problem but i cannot call break inside my iteration. Maybe i should do it inside my recursive function ?  I posted the recursive function, It's big and that why i didnt post it at begining

Comment: there's a way get the depth of each node in you example ? and also get an array of childrens like in the json output i posted ? Cause i just have a flat array with the sample your provided. Thanks

Comment: Edit to accommodate your latest requirement. Next time please try to get this stuff asked in your original post so I don't waste my time.

Comment: I meant to limit the level in my recursive function, not the one you posted. So hopefully my last question is : if i use your function, i need to create another recursive function that will put the children, paths and display a json Output like the one i posted in my question ? or i can just output a json directly inside the GetDescendents function