# Remove elements from a list of objects while iterating

Tags: c#, list

I have a list of id/parents that i'm iterating through an external extension. This list can have around 11 000 lines and that's why i need to remove some elements so i will just display the ones i need.

**List of elements :**

```
FlatData[] elements = new FlatData[]
{
   new FlatData {Id = 3, ParentId = 1, Text = "A"}, 
   new FlatData {Id = 4, ParentId = 1, Text = "D"},
   new FlatData {Id = 5, ParentId = 2, Text = "E"},
   new FlatData {Id = 7, ParentId = 2, Text = "G"},
   new FlatData {Id = 8, ParentId = 4, Text = "H"},
   new FlatData {Id = 9, ParentId = 8, Text = "H"},
   new FlatData {Id = 10, ParentId = 8, Text = "I"},
   new FlatData {Id = 11, Text = "I"},
};
```

While i'm iterating, i want to remove some elements so they will not be processed or displayed, but the element i want to remove still present in the output !

Here's the code iterating trough the elements:

```
int firstDepth = 0;

IEnumerable <DeepNodeData> nodes = elements.Where(x => x.Id >= 4).RecursiveJoin(element => element.Id,
     element => element.ParentId,
    (FlatData element, int index, int depth, IEnumerable<DeepNodeData> children) =>
     {
          int  position;

          if(depth == 0){
            firstDepth++;
          }

          if(firstDepth > 0){
              position= Array.FindIndex(elements, row => row.Id == index);
              elements.Skip(position);
          }

          return new DeepNodeData()
          {
              Id = element.Id,
              Index = index,
              Text = element.Text,
          };
    });
```

I only know the starting position (the id = 4) which is the root parent. I will only know the positions of the elements i want to remove once i have the depth value. The idea is to display only the childrens attached to the id = 4. Here's the elements i should have at the end and that should be processed to built my treeview:

```
FlatData[] elements = new FlatData[]
 {
     new FlatData {Id = 4, ParentId = 1, Text = "D" },
     new FlatData {Id = 8, ParentId = 4, Text = "H" },
     new FlatData {Id = 9, ParentId = 8, Text = "H" },
 };
```

The Recusive Extension :

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> RecursiveJoin<TSource, TKey, TResult>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
     Func<TSource, TKey> parentKeySelector,
     Func<TSource, TKey> childKeySelector,
     Func<TSource, int, int, IEnumerable<TResult>, TResult> resultSelector)
  {
    return RecursiveJoin(source, parentKeySelector, childKeySelector,
       resultSelector, Comparer<TKey>.Default);
  }

  public static IEnumerable<TResult> RecursiveJoin<TSource, TKey, TResult>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
     Func<TSource, TKey> parentKeySelector,
     Func<TSource, TKey> childKeySelector,
     Func<TSource, int, int, IEnumerable<TResult>, TResult> resultSelector,
     IComparer<TKey> comparer)
  {
    // prevent source being enumerated more than once per RecursiveJoin call
    source = new LinkedList<TSource>(source);

    // fast binary search lookup
    SortedDictionary<TKey, TSource> parents = new SortedDictionary<TKey, TSource>(comparer);
    SortedDictionary<TKey, LinkedList<TSource>> children
       = new SortedDictionary<TKey, LinkedList<TSource>>(comparer);

    foreach (TSource element in source)
    {
      parents[parentKeySelector(element)] = element;

      LinkedList<TSource> list;

      TKey childKey = childKeySelector(element);

      if (!children.TryGetValue(childKey, out list))
      {
        children[childKey] = list = new LinkedList<TSource>();
      }

      list.AddLast(element);
    }

    // initialize to null otherwise compiler complains at single line assignment
    Func<TSource, int, IEnumerable<TResult>> childSelector = null;

    childSelector = (TSource parent, int depth) =>
    {
      LinkedList<TSource> innerChildren = null;

      if (children.TryGetValue(parentKeySelector(parent), out innerChildren))
      {
        return innerChildren.Select((child, index)
           => resultSelector(child, index, depth , childSelector(child, depth + 1)));
      }
      return Enumerable.Empty<TResult>();
    };

    return source.Where(element => !parents.ContainsKey(childKeySelector(element)))
       .Select((element, index) => resultSelector(element, index, 0 ,childSelector(element, 1)));
  }
```

Comment: Can you post the code of your RecursiveJoin extension as well?

Comment: Done. I just posted it

Comment: "The idea is to display only the childrens attached to the id = 4", but in your example you are filtering by all items with id >= 5?

Comment: Sorry my bad, it sould be i > =4. I updated the post

Comment: @Isma, or maybe you have a better suggestion on how to build the tree structure by getting the depth number

Comment: Duplicate (repost) of [Remove element from an array of objects while iterating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50864105/remove-element-from-an-array-of-objects-while-iterating)